# Python typehints: Union[int, List[int]] - Unsupported target for indexed assignment

Tags: python, list, union, type-hinting, mypy

`myunionA` may be a *integer* or a *list of integers*.
How do I write typehints to reflect this?

It tried the following code and tested it using mypy. The last line fails  - see the error text.

```
numbers: List[int]
myunionA: Union[int, List[int]]
myunionB: Union[int, List[int]]

numbers = [11, 22]
numbers[2] = 3
myunionA = 2
myunionB[2] = 22 # ERROR(mypy): Unsupported target for indexed assignment
```

How to I write a typehint which lets me assign a integer or a list of integers?

Comment: You can't safely assign to an index of `Union[int, List[int]]`, because you don't know whether it's an `int` or `List[int]`, and the operation will fail on one of the two. The type hint is correct and so is the error. You need to write additional code to narrow down the possibility of which type it will be at runtime. (I do not know how to do that in a way that satisfied mypy specifically, as I have no experience with it.)

Answer (score 5):

As deceze said in the comments, your code is genuinely unsound. What if somebody were to do the following?

```
# Legal, since myunionB can be *either* int or List[int]
myunionB: Union[int, List[int]] = 99

# Boom! At runtime, we get a "int is not subscriptable" error
myunionB[2] = 22
```

If you want mypy to understand that your union currently happens to be a list, you'll need narrow the type of your variable performing an isinstance check or the like.

```
if isinstance(myunionB, list):
    # Type of myunionB is understood to be just List[int] here,
    # so this type-checks
    myunionB[2] = 22
else:
    # And myunionB is understood to be just int here
    myunionB = 100

# Alternatively, you can use an assert
assert isinstance(myunionB, list)
myunionB[2] = 22
```

Or even better, redesign your code so that you don't need the union to begin with and have it just be a `List[int]`. In most cases, it's a good idea to try and minimize your use of Union types -- doing this often (though not always!) ends up making your code simpler and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Type annotations have *no* effect at run time. Just because you have indicated that `myUnionB` *should* be either an `int` or list of `ints`, you never actually *defined* it to be a list, let alone one with at least 3 elements such that you can assign to `myunionB[2]`.

The error message could probably be clearer; `myunionB` is an unsupported target because the name doesn't exist yet. A variable annotation does not "create" a variable, because it doesn't assign any value (even an implicit `None`) to the name being annotated.